# Existence of a limit and a counterexample

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples

For homework, my group was given this false statement which we were supposed to find an example for:

If a function $g$ is bounded from top and bottom on an open interval $(a,b)$, then there exists a real number (non infinite) limit:
$$\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x) $$

We were trying to come up with a solution but we think that there is no counterexample, as when a function is bounded from both sides, it must have a real number lmit at the ends of the function. Are we wrong?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x$ rational and $1$ for $x$ irratioinal.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your answer. But if i have a function f(x) = 0 that is indeed bounded from top and bottom on a random interval, if I went and tried to find the limit at $b^-$, then it would still be zero. So it still is a real number limit and not a counterexample, as the limit must approach zero, right?

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ on the $(-1,0)$ interval? The function is bounded, and I don't think the limit when $x \rightarrow 0^-$ exists.

Comment: @ampersander The function provided by Kavi is not $0$ on any interval.

Comment: @user3733558 wanna post your comment as an answer? I will flag it as the correct one, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(As requested by the OP)*

It seems to me that $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ considered on the $(-1,0)$ interval provides a counter-example, since $f(x)$ is bounded on the interval, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x)$ is undefined.